# ORC Format scan all table in each query

Tags: performance, amazon-athena, snappy, orc

I created my first orc table in Athena.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `orc_test`(
 `hexid` string,
 `version` int,
 `ts` int,
 `campaignid` int,
 `sourceuid` string,
 `publisherid` string,
 `adslot` string,
 `share` double,
 `earn` double,
 `spent` double,
 `rebate` double,
 `payout` double,
 `cost` double,
 `ip` string,
 `useragent` string,
 `referer` string,
 `param1` string,
 `param2` string,
 `param3` string,
 `param4` string,
 `param5` string,
 `param6` string,
 `appid` string,
 `bundleid` string,
 `deviceid` string,
 `uuid` string,
 `callbackurl` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
 `year` string,
 `month` string,
 `day` string,
 `hour` string,
 `minute` string) 
STORED AS orc
LOCATION
 ‘s3://someplace/orc_2’
TBLPROPERTIES (‘orc.compress’=‘SNAPPY’)
```

When I do a query searching for a specific data (for example a hexid). The query scans the entire table. Being a columnar table, wouldn't have it to search only on the hexId column, without scanning the entire table?

I think that I'm missing something.

Thank you!

pd: sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will reduce the data scanned only when you use partition columns in your WHERE clause, so that Athena can identify a subset of partitions to scan.  In your table definition, hexid is not a partition field, so Athena must scan the entire data set to identify rows.

See [Partitioning Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) in the Athena docs for more.

Comment: thanks for the answer @James. So, in these case, what's the difference with the ORC format (columnar) and JSON format?. Because you can create partitions in json table too. What's the benefit of a columnar format if it scan all the table?

Comment: Good question, @justMiLa, I've ended up using JSON myself because the effort of conversion did not seem to make sense.  The docs are not helpful on this point.  My guess is that columnar formats help Athena response faster, even if the IO charge is the same or nearly the same.

Comment: Also see [Top 10 Performance Tuning Tips for Amazon Athena - 5. Optimize columnar data store generation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/).  It suggests the columnar formats could reduce IO by skipping blocks where the block statistics allowed.

Comment: Thanks Again @James. Something strange happened yesterday. I did the same tests with the Parquet format, and it didn't scan all the table.  When i searched by any column, it only scanned these column (without partitions). So, the problem is with ORC format, but i don't know where...

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at this post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=841338#841338
It seems that columnar read availability depends on ORC stripe size. As defaulted in Presto to 8MB (and Athena uses Presto), your ORC file must contain stripes larger than 8MB. Below that limit, the whole file will be read.

AWS Athena does not have this problem with Parquet files. However, be careful with complex parquet data types:

*"When you query columns with complex data types (array, map, struct), and are using Parquet for storing data, Athena currently reads an entire row of data, instead of selectively reading only the specified columns as expected. This is a known issue."*
(all limitations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html)